Customized highlighting of a markdown text document with Pandoc
Using Pandoc to render PDF from a Markdown text file, I use highlighting code blocks to format a different type of text, like this:
this is normal text

~~~~~~
this is special text
~~~~~~

The snippet of special text is always rendered with a fixed font and size, and, what is worst, newline characters are inserted automatically, so long lines extend to the right side and don't show up.
Where is this default format defined, and how to adapt it to a text-oriented (instead of code-oriented) content?

Could you explain the connection with TeX? As currently stated, your question seems to be off-topic for this site and might be better asked elsewhere.

I think that is not the same issue. The question is that the code produces a verbatim environment  that s not expected because there is no wrapping (and maybe because is also separated from the plain text?, not sure what  "newline characters are inserted automatically" mean ... )  but there is simpler markdown syntax to produce wrapped monospaced text without deal with fenced div blocks.

Short answer:
foo `bar` baz

Long answer:
The purpose of code markdown blocks is precisely not to format the text in any way, only to show it "as is" with a monospaced font to distinguish that is not plain text but a programming language.
This is what should be used if you want to obtain a verbatim environment in LaTeX:
foo
\begin{verbatim}
bar 
\end{verbatim}
baz

However, it seems that what you want is `inline code`  between single grave accents to produce inline code as in this site, for instance), which is not the equivalent to inline verbatim in LaTeX, i.e., it will be not exported to \verb|inline code| but normal text with teletype (monospaced) font: \texttt{inline\ code }.
This is a good decision because inline verbatim is problematic in several scenarios and cannot be wrapped, but note that the normal space ( ) is exported to a control space (\ ) to fake the verbatim style. Also it could make  others changes to avoid errors due to active characters in the code. Said that you have as &  %  \foo.This be exported "as is" in verbatim text but not as   \texttt{&  %  \foo} since this will cause three errors. Pandoc solved this issue in this way: \texttt{\&\ \ \%\ \ \textbackslash{}foo} (nothing to worry about, because in the PDF will look good anyway).
BTW, the true highlight can be obtained in code blocks (not in line code) if you specify the language at the start of the code block, but note that the label {=latex} has a very different meaning than just the label latex. A small comparison to clarify:

---
format: pdf
highlight-style: dracula
classoption: twocolumn
callout-appearance: simple
geometry:
  - columnsep=1cm
  - margin=0.5cm   
---

## Normal text

Normal text before.
    This is normal \LaTeX\ text.
    This       is    normal     \LaTeX\  text.
Normal text after.

::: {.callout-note}
- [ ] New lines (paragraph breaks)
- [x] Automatic line breaks.
- [ ] Maintain spaces.
- [ ] Monospaced font.
- [ ] Syntax highlight. 
:::

## \LaTeX\ code chunk

Normal text before.
```{=latex}
This is normal \LaTeX\ text.
This      is     normal    \LaTeX\    text. 
```
Normal text after.

::: {.callout-note}
- [x] New lines (paragraph breaks)
- [ ] Automatic line breaks.
- [ ] Maintain spaces.
- [ ] Monospaced font.
- [ ] Syntax highlight. 
:::


# Verbatim text

Normal text before.
```         
This is normal \LaTeX\ text.
This      is     normal    \LaTeX\    text. 
```
Normal text after.


::: {.callout-note}
- [x] New lines (paragraph breaks)
- [ ] Automatic line breaks.
- [x] Maintain spaces.
- [x] Monospaced font.
- [ ] Syntax highlight. 
:::

\newpage

# Syntax highlight

Normal text before.

``` latex
This is normal \LaTeX\ text.
This      is     normal    \LaTeX\    text. 
```

Normal text after.


::: {.callout-note}
- [x] New lines (paragraph breaks)
- [ ] Automatic line breaks.
- [x] Maintain spaces.
- [x] Monospaced font.
- [x] Syntax highlight. 
:::

# Inline code

Normal text before. `This is normal \LaTeX\ text.
This      is     normal    \LaTeX\    text.` Normal text after.

::: {.callout-note}
- [ ] New lines (paragraph breaks)
- [x] Automatic line breaks.
- [x] Maintain spaces.
- [x] Monospaced font.
- [ ] Syntax highlight. 
:::

